# How to properly form animation xml with multiple rotate tags

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-animation

I want to make an animation-list with multiple items and each item contains a rotate tag . What is the proper way to form it ? Is there an other way to do the same ? Here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true" >
    <rotate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="50"
        android:pivotX="301"
        android:pivotY="334"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:startOffset="0"
    />



    <rotate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:fromDegrees="50"
        android:toDegrees="20"
        android:pivotX="301"
        android:pivotY="334"
        android:duration="859"
        android:startOffset="0"
    />

</set>
```

I want this xml to repeat when its over . Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please split the rotate to 2 animation xml files "rotate_0_50.xml" & "rotate_50_20.xml" and try the code below:

```
final Animation anim0_50 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_0_50);
final Animation anim50_20 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_50_20);

final View animView = findViewById(R.id.anim_view)
anim0_50.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}            
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        animView.startAnimation(anim50_20);                         
    }
});

anim50_20.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {            
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}            
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        animView.startAnimation(anim0_50);                          
    }
});

animView.startAnimation(anim0_50);
```